# Queue with time

Tags: c++, queue, task-queue

My solution passes basic tests... But I came up with 1 test that kills it. What did I do wrong?

> Problem: A hospital in the city of N is asking for your help. During the pandemic there are too many visitors at the doctor's office. The doctor's appointment lasts for exactly K
> minutes. If a visitor arrives at the moment when the therapist is already taking someone, he gets in a queue. No one likes lines, so before you take any action, the hospital administration has asked you to find the maximum length of the line for the last day.

- The first line of input data contains two integers N - the number of
  visitors for the last day and K - the duration of the reception of 1
  patient.
- The second line contains N numbers, sorted in ascending order: ti -
  the time when the i-th visitor came to see the therapist.
- The output should contain a single integer - the maximum queue length
  of the last day.

```c
    #include <iostream>
    #include <queue>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
        int n, k;
        int res = 0;
        queue<int> q;
        cin >> n >> k;
    
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            int t;
            cin >> t;
    
            while (!q.empty() && q.front() <= t) {
                    q.pop();
            }
            res = res < q.size() ? q.size() : res;
            q.push(t+k);
        }
        cout << res;
        return 0;
    }
```

Basic tests:
**5 2**
**1 4 6 8 20**
(result 0)
**6 5**
**0 5 10 15 19 25**
(result 1)

My test:
**10 10**
**11 16 44 67 74 79 82 89 93 95**
(result 2, but there should be more)

Comment: You've tagged this as `C`, but it is clearly `C++`

Comment: You're assuming that every patient arriving at `t` will be finished by `t+k`, which is not the case. Think a little more about how a (fair) queue works.

Comment: Create a variable for patients in queue, and wait time. Enqueue the arrive times to the queue. Dequeue at the respective time t using a loop structure. Update the wait times and queue as needed. Save the max queue length. This is high level pseudo code. Since this appear to be a HW problem, I will hold back posting the solution. . This is an interesting problem, Challenge yourself. I get answer of 4 for the 10 10 test.

Comment: You seem to have a queue of finishing times. So, imagine that you arrive at a queue and wait at the back of it like a good citizen. You are told that the processing time is exactly ten minutes per person. Do you expect to leave ten minutes after you arrived, or ten minutes after the person in front you has been processed?